# How to convert "2020-10-08 09:38:08" into March, 2020 format using jquery

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-ui, date-formatting, jquerydatetimepicker

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('M dd', date)
```

I have tried this but its giving me error

> jquery-ui.js:8924 Uncaught TypeError: date.getDate is not a function

Comment: What is `date`? Seems it's not a `Date` instance [as required](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate)

Comment: its a date from database like created_at date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `formatDate` method expects a `Date` instance.

If you're starting with that particular string, you can easily convert it to ISO 8601 format then parse it into a `Date` instance

```js
const date = "2020-10-08 09:38:08"
const dateInstance = new Date(date.replace(" ", "T"))

const formatted = $.datepicker.formatDate('M dd', dateInstance)
```